# What is wrong with my androidmanifest? launcher icon label does not appear

Tags: java, android, android-studio, uilabel, android-manifest

When I run my simple app the app label doesn't appear on my launcher. I tried to fix with all that I could, But nothing id different. This is my `manifest.xml`

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="com.marc.torch"
 android:versionCode="1"
 android:versionName="1.0">

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_torch"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

This is my String file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <resources>
    <string name="app_name">Torch</string>
  </resources>
</manifest>
```

**Screenshot:**
[image: this is my screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You are using the "FullscreenTheme".
I am suggest you that if you want to display a label then change your theme go to the styles and change the theme.

Comment: Hi Aakash Jain thanks. Please check my screenshot picture.

Comment: <style name="FullscreenTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar">
 <item name="android:colorPrimary">@android:color/black</item>
 <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>

Comment: your windowFullscreen is true just change it to false

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your string.xml file ?
app_name must be defined over there.....

Comment: HI Akash Rastogi I have <string name="app_name">Torch</string> in my string.xml thanks

Answer (score 0):

1)you might have spelling or capital letter mistake with this FullscreenTheme

2)check your FullscreenTheme (style) in res->values->strins.xml

3)you might find something similiar to this.

```
<style name="AppFullScreenTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
     <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
     <item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>
     <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
     <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
 </style>
```

4) Remove NoActionBar from the parent.

5)change the values of the screen as required by simply changing there values.